# Finding Values in a Panda Series that can't be Converted to a Particular Datatype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called df which has a series, let's called it 'date', that have strings that refer to dates of the format 'YYYY-mm-dd' and hence every single value on the series should only have strings that can be converted to datetime objects.

I need to be able to show/filter only the rows which values on the df['date'] can't be converted to a datetime object so I can review them and decide what to do with those values, or at least know how many of them there are before removing them from df.

I looked into `isintance(value, datetime)`, but I can't seem to figure out a way to apply that to pandas series, I figure, I could do it in a non-pythonic way with an apply-lamba option but I was hoping to not having to resort to that.

I thought also about doing it with `df[datetimeFromDate] = pd.to_datetime(df['date], errors='coerce')` and then filter by `df[datetimeFromDate].isnull()` which is fine, and possibly more pythonic but I was really hoping to do it in one liner and I'm not thrilled about having to add another column, if I can avoid it.

Comment: post a testable df with both valid and invalid `date` string values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show errant rows, you can use in one line:

```
dfx = df[df['Date'].map(lambda x: pd.isnull(pd.to_datetime(x, errors = 'coerce')))]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do it in one line but that's not what I would do :-)
However, for the challenge...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2023-03-22', 'hello', '2023/03/21']})

df['datetimeFromDate'], m = (
    pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce').to_frame()
      .assign(m=lambda x: x.isna()).to_dict('series').values()
)
```

For `Python>=3.8`, you can use the `walrus` operator, and this is Pythonic!

```
df['datetimeFromDate'], m = \
    (dt := pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')), dt.isna()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         date datetimeFromDate
0  2023-03-22       2023-03-22
1       hello              NaT
2  2023/03/21       2023-03-21

>>> m
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: m, dtype: bool
```